Looking for simple tool for making contour maps
I'd like to make a contour map of several small areas and export it as an image or Google Earth file.
I'm not a GIS professional so looking for something quick and easy. I've found contourmapcreator.urgr8.ch but it's buggy and the underlying data from Google Elevation API is minimal and low quality.
Are there any better options?

Where abouts in the world are you mapping? data source might be as important as the methodology.

@Sethinacan US and Canada currently but hoping for something global

The only global data source I know of is the SRTM but you can get more detailed data in different ways for different coverages.  https://www.opendem.info/srtm_contours.html

You can use contourmap.app which is a similar contour map generator but much more modern, easy to use and the underlying data is more detailed.
Some features are paid but the free mode is really good and sufficient for most applications.
